# Android include all dependencies in a output library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, fatjar

I've created an android library which use itself another library (aar). When i use my generated aar file in a new project i can not execute functions which use the other library code. How can generate an aar with all library dependencies included?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `api` for adding your dependencies in your library instead of using `implementation. Using`api` will expose your dependencies to the world. Something like this:

```
dependencies {
  api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  api 'com.your.library:libraryName:1.0'
}
```

Comment: Still having the same behavior here is my Gradle: `api files('com.library2.android.sdk-release.aar')` the error in the test app is:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/library2/android/sdk/SDKManager;` any advice? – user7848257 12 mins ago